# CorePageApp Exception: The null object does not have a method 'open'

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, core-elements

I am running an app with DartEditor (not dart-eclipse plugin)

```
Dart Editor version 1.10.0.dev_01_01 (DEV)
Dart SDK version 1.10.0-dev.1.1
```

I am consistently getting the following when the app is executed

Exception: The null object does not have a method 'open'.

```
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'open'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [] (package:polymer_snippet/material_design/core_page`/core_page_app.dart:41)`
```

The offending open() is the last line in the CarePageApp attached() method below:

```
 @override
  void attached()
  {
    super.attached();
    pfm = $['pfm'] as PaperFabMenu ;
    pfm.open(); // pfm seems to be null

  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

NB: There is no specific code for me to attach.

Comment: Have you checked if it is `null` (also without `as PaperFabMenu`)? Do you add `<paper-fab-menu id="pfm">` dynamically (by code, within `<template if="{{}}">` or within `<template repeat="{{}}">`?

Comment: You are so correct Gunter. My stupidity. I actually had the nul PFM in my code. I had to search for it with a grep tool. Solved.